# VSCode doesn't autocomplete when text is highlighted after another autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

When editing text on visual studio code, when I use autocomplete for something (like in the picture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WKnm.png

It highlights my text (while typing) and autocomplete stops working

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjK6T.png

Same goes when I autocomplete an if statement

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPNVX.png

Is there any way to disable that highlight, or make it autocomplete even with the highlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your settings.json file, it'll prevent this behaviour:

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,
```

Answer (score 5):

If you **wanted** autocomplete dropdown ***while code is highlighted***
(for example: After you performed an autocomplete and VS Code auto highlights for you):

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

^^^ in your settings.json ^^^

Example action:
Editing a html doc: you typed 'clas...' in a div

```
<div clas..>
     Something...
<div>
```

It should autocomplete to

```
<div class="HIGHLIGHTEDTXT">
     Something...
<div>
```

with ***HIGHLIGHTEDTXT***, you can type any things and the autocomplete dropdown will be shown.

P.S.

The autocomplete dropdown will not appear if the settings is set to *TRUE* when a text is highlighted.