# Auto Complete in VSCode for Go it's sometimes bugged or with misconfiguration

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When I'm coding in Go, sometimes the VSCode show this green lines (look at the image below) and the auto complete stops functioning correctly. Idk if it's some misconfiguration or a bug in some settings of Go extension. I've tried to look on the gopls settings but couldn't find anything that helps

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61322351) work for you (setting `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` to `false`)? I just tried it and it seems to work, not 100% sure though

Comment: Yes! I've just tried and seems to work. Even when the line gets green (I'm not sure why tho) the auto complete works fine. Thankss @xarantolus